# How to carry-over the calculated value within the RDD ? -Apache spark

Tags: syntax, apache-spark

**SOLVED:  There is no good solution to this problem**

I am sure that this is just a syntax-relevant question and that answer is an easy one.

---

What I am trying to achieve is to:

-pass a variable to RDD

-change the variable according to RDD data

-get the adjusted variable

---

Lets say I have:

var b = 2

val x = sc.parallelize(0 to 3)

what I want to do is to obtain the value 2+0 + 2+0+1 + 2+0+1+2  + 2+0+1+2+3 = 18
That is, the value 18 by doing something like

b = x.map(i=> … b+i...).collect

The problem is, for each i, I need to carry over the value b, to be incremented with the next i

I want to use this logic for adding the elements to an array that is external to RDD

How would I do that without doing the collect first ?

Comment: This is not at all an easy syntax-related question. What you are trying to do is impossible. It goes against the entire concept of what an RDD is, and distributed computing in general. I suggest you describe more specifically what problem you are trying to solve and let us offer a solution that fits with the concepts in play. You can also check out `RDD.aggregate` which is similar to what you are trying to do, but works within the distributed world.

Comment: aggregate is OK, except that I need to pass one parameter (which is the variable "b" from the question) instead of the necessary two.  I hope you are right that this is not just a syntax question, and that it cannot be done with a Spark.

What I am trying to do is to : 1. pass the collection to RDD 2. Add elements from RDD to a collection 3. Retrieve a collection  NOTE: I do not mind if the resulting collection is not in an order, I can always sort by index at the end. I just do not want to do the collect first, and then generate a collection from it.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot do that. The RDD is distributed. It's on other machines. You cannot just pass it a mutable collection, put some stuff in it and get it back. However, this sounds very similar to a filter. Why not filter the RDD and then collect the results? You can append them to your collection at that point.

Comment: Thank you!  I will make a good note of it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's not possible to mutate one variable with the contents of an RDD as RDDs are distributed across potentially many different nodes while mutable variables are local to each executor (JVM).

Although not particularly performant, it's possible to implement these requirements on Spark by translating the sequential algorithm in a series of transformations that can be executed in a distributed environment.

Using the same example as on the question, this algorithm in Spark could be expressed as:

```
val initialOffset = 2
val rdd = sc.parallelize(0 to 3)
val halfCartesian = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter{case (x,y) => x>=y}
val partialSums = halfCartesian.reduceByKey(_ + _) 
val adjustedPartials = partialSums.map{case (k,v) => v+initialOffset}
val total = adjustedPartials.reduce(_ + _)

scala> total
res33: Int = 18
```

Note that `cartesian` is a very expensive transformation as it creates (m x n) elements, or in this case n^2.
This is just to say that it's not impossible, but probably not ideal.

If the amount of data to be processed sequentially would fit in the memory of one machine (maybe after filtering/reduce), then Scala has a built-in collection operation to realize exactly what's being asked: `scan[Left|Right]`

```
val arr = Array(0,1,2,3)
val cummulativeScan = arr.scanLeft(initialOffset)(_ + _)
// we remove head b/c scan adds the given element at the start of the sequence 
val result = cummulativeScan.tail.sum

result: Int = 18
```